# Google Spreadsheet multiple column filter using OR

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have a Google Spreadsheet with 3 columns that are either blank or have a value.  I want to get the count of the number of rows that has A and either B or C populated.  If I were writing a SQL query it would be

```
select count(*) 
from Table 
where A is not null and (B is not null or C is not null)
```

But I can't for the life of me figure out how to get this in a Google Spreadsheet

Answer (score 33, accepted):

The formula below should do what you are after:

```
=ROWS(FILTER(A2:A, NOT(ISBLANK(A2:A)), NOT(ISBLANK(B2:B))+NOT(ISBLANK(C2:C)) ))
```

And to explain:

- [`ROWS`](http://docs.google.com/support/bin/answer.py?answer=82712&funcType=Lookup&query=ROWS&searchSyntaxExact=1) counts the rows of the argument (filtered, in our case)
- [`FILTER`](http://docs.google.com/support/bin/answer.py?answer=82712&funcType=Lookup&query=FILTER&searchSyntaxExact=1) returns the rows of arg1 (`A2:A`) that all subsequent arguments match
- The `+` (addition) symbol combines two predicates with a logical `OR`

Finally, if you are not using header columns you can change the references from `A2:A` to `A:A`

Alternatively, you can use the [`QUERY`](http://docs.google.com/support/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=159999) function:

*(Broken into multiple lines for readability)*

```
=ROWS(QUERY(A2:C, 
    "SELECT A WHERE A IS NOT NULL AND (B IS NOT NULL OR C IS NOT NULL)"))
```

For more information on the syntax of the queries, see the [Visualization API Query Language Reference](http://code.google.com/apis/visualization/documentation/querylanguage.html) and specifically the [Language Reference](http://code.google.com/apis/visualization/documentation/querylanguage.html#Language_Syntax)

Comment: Awesome , that QUERY function...I didn't even know it existed!   Thanks!

Comment: where is the documentation for the use of the '+' symbol as a boolean OR?

Answer (score 0):

```
=SUMPRODUCT(((A:A<>"")*((B:B<>"")+(C:C<>"")))>0)
```

if there is only one argument for SUMPRODUCT() it works just as SUM(ARRAYFORMULA(N( )))