# Google Spreadsheet multiple column filter condition grouping syntax

Tags: google-docs, google-sheets

This question is somewhat similar to

[Google Spreadsheet multiple column filter using OR](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2512782/google-spreadsheet-multiple-column-filter-using-or)

but where as he asks for the equivalent of:

```
select count(*) 
from Table 
where A is not null and (B is not null or C is not null)
```

I would like to do:

```
select count(*) 
from Table 
where A is not null OR (B is not null AND C is not null)
```

In fact what I am trying to do is filter on a date and I have been using

```
=FILTER(YEAR(Hours!A2:A)=2012,MONTH(Hours!A2:A)>=8)
```

to give me August going forward.

but now I need to add a limit to a certain day for the month. I would need something like this:

=FILTER(MONTH(Hours!A2:A)=8, **(** MONTH(Hours!A2:A)=9 **AND** DAY(Hours!A2:A)<=13) **)**

in order to have **all of** August and then September **only** up to the 13th.

Is there a Syntax that allows this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> to have all of August and then September only up to the 13th.

One way (and this would be a "general" solution for filtering between two dates):

`=COUNT(FILTER(Hours!A2:A;Hours!A2:A>=DATE(2012;8;1);Hours!A2:A<=DATE(2012;9;13)))`

Comment: Great! Simple solution. One of those ones that says.. uf! why didn't I think of that. I can't vote it up - I'm too new.